# How do I adhere vinyl sheeting to carpet?

Tags: installation, vinyl-flooring

We foster puppies on a regular basis and in order to protect the carpet I am looking to cover a section of their room with vinyl sheet flooring where their pen is located.  I thought about vinyl because it is inexpensive and waterproof.

I need to know how to adhere it to the carpet for an extended period of time (6 months) without damaging the carpet when it is removed.  It needs to be fairly secure and I want to prevent the edges from curling up.

Any ideas on how best to adhere the vinyl?  I am also open to other floor covering solutions.

Comment: I applaud you for fostering puppies, but I'd really suggest having a non-carpetted room (or garage) before making that type of commitment.

Comment: Personally as the pups were Westies I used a childs pool that way they were contained and the Momma could jump in and out.

Comment: How big of an area do you need waterproofed?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a good answer to your question.  What you want to do is ... poorly thought out.

Get a small section of vinyl and unroll it so that the edges extend beyond the edge of the pen.  Let the pen hold it down.  Anything more is not going to be good for the carpet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That was my first thought about placing the pen on top but wanted something a little more permanent.  Maybe I should go so far as to build a wooden framework with plywood flooring that the vinyl can be adhered to?  As I stated in my original post I'm open to other more thought out suggestions.  Kind of at a loss without having half (or all) of the room replaced with a waterproof solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about an alternative? Check with commercial supply companies like Cintas or U-Line. They make door mats in some pretty large sizes that are rubber on the bottom and have a lip around the edge. The inside is either carpet or raised rubber ridges or nubs.

[Here's an example from U-Line](http://www.uline.com/BL_1770/Rubberized-Entry-Mats):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about making a temporary floor out of plywood that sits on the carpet.  It can be covered with vinyl.

I would make  raised edges so that any spilt water, urine or other mess would be contained.

Answer (score 0):

Buy some carpet wrap.  Put it on every sq inch of your room - $10.  Lay vinyl down with a few dabs of construction adhesive (not around the carpet wrap seams) - adhesive $5.  It will hold well enough.